# WordPress Contributor Moderation Comments

Tags: wordpress, comments, user-permissions

If user has permission "Contributor" in Admin Page can View the comments awaiting moderation but i need to disable this.

In user roles with "View comments Awaiting Moderation" its not present nothing.

How to disable the /wp-admin/edit-comments.php?comment_status=moderated for Contributor users?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Modify the comments query**

Here's one suggestion, to adjust the comment status for the `get_comments()` input  arguments, with help of the `pre_get_comments` action:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_comments', function( \WP_Comment_Query $query )
{   
    // Only target edit-comments.php
    if( ! did_action( 'load-edit-comments.php' ) )
        return;

    // Only target users that can't publish posts
    if( current_user_can( 'publish_posts' ) )
        return;

    // Halt the query for pending comments      
    if( 'hold' === $query->query_vars['status'] )
        $query->query_vars['status'] = 'non-existent';

    // Remove pending comments from the 'all' or '' status view
    if( in_array( $query->query_vars['status'], [ 'all', '' ], true ) )
        $query->query_vars['status'] = 'approve';   
} );
```

where we target only the `edit-comments.php` page and modify the status to `approve` if it's empty or `'all'` for users that can't publish posts.
Here we assign the comment status to a non existent status to remove the list of pending comments.

It can be a little confusing all the various status values for *pending* comments,  e.g.

```
hold, pending, moderated, '0'
```

depending if it's a label, a comment query variable or how it's stored in the database,

**Modify the comments counts**

*All* comments count here:

[image: all]

means the sum of the `Approved + Pending` comments counts.

When we change the comment query, like above, these comment status counts will not change. We might want to adjust that too.

Here's an example how we can adjust the comments counts via the `wp_count_comments` filter:

```
add_filter( 'wp_count_comments', 'wpse_count_comments', 10, 2 );

function wpse_count_comments( $counts, $post_id  )
{
    // Only target the backend
    if( !  is_admin() )
        return $counts;

    // Only target users that can't publish posts    
    if( current_user_can( 'publish_posts' ) )
        return $counts;

    // Avoid infinite loop before calling wp_count_comments()    
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );    
    $counts = wp_count_comments( $counts, $post_id  );
    add_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__, 10, 2 );

    // Subract 'moderated' count from 'all' count
    $counts->all = $counts->all - $counts->moderated;

    // Set 'moderated' count to zero
    $counts->moderated = 0;

    return $counts;
}
```

This will also remove the counting number, for users that can't publish posts, from the admin menu here:

[image: pending]

**Modify the comment status links**

Finally we might want to remove the status link for *pending* comments, for users that can't publish posts:

```
add_filter( 'comment_status_links', function( $status )
{
    if( ! current_user_can( 'publish_posts' ) )
        unset( $status['moderated'] );
    return $status;
} );
```

So it will become:

[image: all]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Wow, perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could bypass it with javascript adding a script only for logged in users with contributor role removing comment rows with unapproved class from dom.

check if user is logged and is contributor:

```
if( is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can('contributor')) {
```

then add a script inline or enqueue a js file with the follwing code:

```
$('#the-comment-list tr.unapproved').remove();
```

check if the comments are visible in any other views and add the corresponding classes to the script to remove them form everywhere

/* edit */

vanilla js script:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("the-comment-list"); 

for (var i = 0; i < elem.childNodes.length; i++) {
   if (/\bunapproved/.test(elem.childNodes[i].className)) {
      elem.childNodes[i].parentNode.removeChild(elem.childNodes[i]);
   }        
}
```

Comment: This capabilities is not configured for Contributor see the image, contributor cannot moderate comments only see the comments awaiting moderation, thanks =(

Comment: function.php
function frontfooter() {
    echo "<script>$('#the-comment-list tr.unapproved').remove();</script>";
}
if( is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can('contributor')) {
 add_action('admin_footer', 'frontfooter');
}
Return: $ is not a function

Comment: Ok its work perfect, but if i open a page the comments are shown and after 1 millisecond are deleted, with slow motion it's possible to capture all comment.

Comment: There is surely a way to achieve this in backend without having the unapproved comments showing at all but I guess this can be a temporary solution until you find a better one. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have found this semi-solution, this code hide comment from comment moderation list, but it remove all comment also moderated comment, its ok for now =)

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/167250/prevent-contributor-to-show-comment-list

```
function filter_comments_by_contributor( $all_comments ) {
    // get the current logged in user
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) {
        // Not logged in.
        return $all_comments;
    } else {
        // Logged in.

        // check if the logged-in user is a contributor
        if ( in_array( 'contributor', (array) $current_user->roles ) ) {

            // check if the user is on wp-admin backend,
            $screen = get_current_screen();
            if ( ! empty( $screen ) && 'edit-comments' == $screen->id ) {

                // get all posts by that contributor
                $args              = array(
                    'author'         => $current_user->ID,
                    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
                    'fields'         => 'ids'
                );
                $contributor_posts = get_posts( $args );

                // unset the comments given on posts other than his/her.
                foreach ( $all_comments as $key => $value ) {
                    if ( ! in_array( $value->comment_post_ID, $contributor_posts ) ) {
                        unset( $all_comments[ $key ] );
                    }
                }
            }

            return $all_comments;
        } else {
            return $all_comments;
        }
    }
}

if( is_user_logged_in() && !current_user_can('manage_options')) {   
    add_filter( 'the_comments', 'filter_comment_by_contributor' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [user role editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) to have a full control on users roles in general and add some exceptions to specific users.